# Efficient way to parse "ddmmyyyyThhmm" string to workable date string

Tags: php, parsing, datetime

I have the following types of strings:

```
17082011T1015
```

In other words: `day month year T hours minutes`.

What would be an efficient way to parse these strings in such a way that I end with something like a MySQL-like date:

```
`2011-08-17 10:15`
```

(There's no MySQL involved here by the way)

It's for Windows PHP < 5.3 so `strptime()` and `date_parse_from_format()`/`DateTime::createFromFormat()` are NOT an option.

Comment: Of course, if MySQL *was* involved you could simply use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: @Álvaro: Yeah, exactly. I was hoping for something similar in PHP. `strptime()` looked like it, but is not available on Windows, and is also a bit wonky cross-platform if I may believe the docs. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just rearranging a string.

```
$date = "17082011T1015";

$day = substr($date, 0, 2);
$month = substr($date, 2, 2);
$year = substr($date, 4, 4);
$hour = substr($date, 9, 2);
$minute = substr($date, 11, 2);

echo $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minute;
```

Comment: exactly, if the string has always that structure, this is the solution.

Comment: @Dan: thanks. Although I was more or less hoping for something like a nice oneliner (you couldn't have known, cause I didn't require this in my question). :D But something like this will work fine also of course, I guess.

Comment: @fireeyedboy - You just need to encapsulate the code inside a function and you'll have your one liner ;)

Comment: @Matt I just saw your solution, and looked pretty good. Why did you retract it? I missed Dan's comment.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Throwing all the substrings concatenated into `strtotime` then passing that to `date` to get the same format you gave `strtotime` to parse back was ... kinda pointless. You already had to split the string into parts, it didn't buy you anything.

Comment: @fireeyedboy Dan was right; while it made the code *shorter* in terms of text, it wasn't adding anything other than a couple of function calls that would have increased the overhead. It might have looked neater, but doing it the simple way (Dan's way) is more efficient. I just got carried away after I started down a road that *might* have ended up nicer but didn't.

Comment: @Dan: O yeah, LOL. :D By the way, I was thinking of using `sscanf()` before asking the question and thought it wouldn't work because too cumbersome, but I think I have found a solution now, that is a little bit more compact. I'll post it as an answer as well.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, you and Dan are right of course. :) It didn't occur to me at first though. Haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'll end up using this solution:

```
sscanf( '17082011T1015', '%02s%02s%04sT%02s%02s', $day, $month, $year, $hours, $minutes );
$datetime = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hours . ':' . $minutes;
```

Before asking the question I didn't realize I could utilize the optional arguments to `sscanf()` to my advantage, and thought I would have to resort to something like this:

```
$parsed = sscanf( '17082011T1015', '%02s%02s%04sT%02s%02s' );
$datetime = $parsed[ 2 ] . '-' . $parsed[ 1 ] . '-' . $parsed[ 0 ] . ' ' . $parsed[ 3 ] . ':' . $parsed[ 4 ];
```

Not too bad either, but I like to be pretty clear as possible with named variables, so that it's obvious what this little routine does.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0, you may use [DateTime::createFromTimeFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create ordinary `DateTime` object from that string.

Should be something like:

```
$str = "17082011T1015";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($str,'DDMMYYYYThhII');
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Can't test it here, only have PHP 5.2. But I think you could figure the right format yourself.

Comment: His question says "It's for Windows PHP < 5.3 so strptime() and date_parse_from_format()/DateTime::createFromFormat() are NOT an option."

Comment: I know I can use this, but I explicitly stated in the question that PHP >= 5.3 is not an option. Maybe you've overlooked this requirement.